# Can't add users to other Teams

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I have a team in crm dynamics 365 and the `isdefault = true` in the team, how can I understand where create teams with the `isdefault = true` flag and where they are filled with users?
If I try create team, the `isdefault = false` flag.

Comment: was my answer helpful?

Comment: Yes man, you're cool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CRM, we have a default Business unit for each organization and we can create child BU structure under this parent BU. Each Business unit will have a default BU Team (owner) and it will get all the users in that BU as members. This is what you are referring `isdefault = true` team. Whenever users BU changed, they will move accordingly. This has huge security implications. Examples: Sales, Sales-APAC, Service, etc

You can also create an owner Team, this will be `isdefault = false` and users can be added/removed based on need. This can also own records, ie records can be assigned to this owner team.

Comment: "and we can create child BU structure under this parent BU" -
didn't understand it, how do I create a child BU if the parent team(default Business unit) also has isdefault = true?

Comment: @JUSTFUN these are some basics - read it thoroughly: https://crmbook.powerobjects.com/system-administration-in-dynamics-365/business-administration/business-units/